# Issue with deployment of Meteor 0.7.0 app to Heroku - Node.js 0.10.22 is required

Tags: node.js, heroku, meteor

Meteor 0.7.0 now uses 0.10.22 version of Node.js but Heroku installs 0.10.21 by default. 
Is there any way to specify custom version of Node.js for Heroku because as far as I know we can't create package.json file in Meteor apps.

Answer (score 0):

Won't meteor just ignore the package.json? Try creating one that only specified Node version.